# Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'Specified cast is not valid. '

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-4, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have an Entity Framework internal question. I have a custom provider which is trying to generate a model from a stored procedure but during the final model generation it is giving the above error.

The complete error messages are below:

Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'Specified cast is not valid.
'.
Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:22.1755758.
Generating the model took 00:00:25.3114884.
Added the connection string to the App.Config file.
Writing the .edmx file took 00:00:00.0008504.

The final output from the sql that gets generated from the entity framework engine is below:

### C1         |C2                 |C3                    |C4                 |C5         |C6         |C7         |C8         |C9                 |C10                   |C11

1          |APP                |SP_TEST2              |NULL               |0          |0          |0          |0          |ID                 |INTEGER               |IN

As you can see, I'm getting correct output but don't know why and which value is causing the issue since I'm unable to debug into the final model generation code. If you know how to debug that part, please let me know. Any help would be highly appreciated.

My table structure is this: CREATE APP.TEST2(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(50));

Thanks.

Comment: what about Allow Null ?? is that true or false for particular fields

Comment: Could you throw up your code so we can take a look? Just the part where you set the data and save it for the EntityModel should be sufficient.

Comment: Since this pass of Entity Framework engine returns an aggregate of Function and Stored proc, The value of C4 is for Function return type. I know the C5 is for IsAggregate, C7 is for IsBuiltIn and C8 is for IsNiladic. Those are for Fuction only. C6 is set to zero. For the stored proc, last three fields matter for sure. Running MySQL entity framework also returns the same output but it generates a model but in my case no model but the error. Comparing with all the .ssdl, .msl and other files, nothing alarming unless I missed something. Anyone dealt with this issue like in MySQL .net connector?

Comment: @LeviFuller - I don't save the data, once you select a stored proc from the wizard and hit 'Finish', the custom provider code generates SQL code to send to the database. Once that happens, entity framework does some processing which I don't see or can debug yet since they are Entity Framework code, then if it is satisfied, it will generate the model. For the case of Table and View objects, they working as expected. I can capture the SQL code and run it myself on my custom sql database and can see the above output which is same output MySQL or SQL Server is generating. Generated SQL 300 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your thoughts. I figured it out. C5 - C8 returns a value of '0' which is of type integer. They need to be of type bool. Once I changed the type to bool for them, it just works.